# How to disable UILocalNotification sound while phone call

Tags: ios, notifications

I want to disable UILocalNotification sound during phone calls. How to tell cocoa that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. `UILocalNotification` does not provide any means of doing this.

The user will have to change the settings there selfs in the settings app.

Answer (score 0):

You can! Since iOS 4.0 you can use `CTCallCenter` from `CoreTelephony.framework`. You can check if the user has a phone call like this:

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h>
```

...

```
CTCallCenter * callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
if ([callCenter currentCalls] == nil) {
    // Play sound
} else {
    // Maybe the same sound but not as loud as the original
}
```

`currentCalls` is an `NSSet` with `CTCall` objects.